# gfortran compiling error, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have some source code from 1992 that I'm trying to compile using `gfortran` in `OS X 10.13`, which fails and gives the following **error message**:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture `x86_64`:   "_fder_", referenced from:
   _MAIN__ in ccM3qbXV.o   "_fluid_", referenced from:
   _MAIN__ in ccM3qbXV.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried compiling on `OS X 10.13` and another machine with `10.12`, using `XCode`, `Xcode` developer tools, `MacPorts`, and `gfortran`, taking care to match the software version with the OS version.

Comment: It looks like the code in the main program is referring to `fluid`.  Can you find the line or lines containing the reference(s) and add them to your post?

Comment: Did you use Xcode to compile a Fortran code? How did you do that?

Comment: It looks like your code is missing some of the functions it is calling. As @wallyk said, it is referencing 'fluid'. I suspect this function is in another file that isn't linked.